# List all directories with spaces in their name

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

I want to list all directories using a shell script. I am using the following code:

```
DIR="$1"

if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
    echo "Usage: $0 {dir-name}"
exit 1
fi

cd "$DIR"
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
for user in $( ls -d */)
do
  for dirs in $( ls -d $PWD/$user*)
  do
    echo $PWD/$user/$dirs;
  done
done
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

It is working for me if that directory don't have any spaces on it, else it split the output for every spaces on it. I got the following output:

```
abhinaba@abhinaba-desktop:~/software$ sh test.sh /media/2C44138344134F48/RB1
ls: cannot access /m: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access dia/2C44138344134F48/RB1/VB*: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /m: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access dia/2C44138344134F48/RB1/DLI*: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /m: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access dia/2C44138344134F48/RB1/3001/*: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /m: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access dia/2C44138344134F48/RB1/VB*: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /m: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access dia/2C44138344134F48/RB1/DLI*: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /m: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access dia/2C44138344134F48/RB1/3002/*: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /m: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access dia/2C44138344134F48/RB1/VB*: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /m: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access dia/2C44138344134F48/RB1/DLI*: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /m: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access dia/2C44138344134F48/RB1/3003/*: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you be more precise on the question: do you need only the directories with space on it? Or do you need to "do your stuff" on all directories, including the ones with space in their name?

Comment: You need to run the script with BASH "bash test.sh /media/2C44138344134F48/RB1"

Comment: I need to list all directories, with or without spaces on it.

Comment: I understood that but the question in the title is not clear. I have updated my answer. I had the same error by running through "sh test.sh ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED: removed `ls` to optimize the script (from `tripleee`)

If you use BASH shell:

```
#!/bin/bash

SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
DIR="$1"

if [ $# -ne 1 ]
 then
 echo "Usage: $0 {dir-name}"
 exit 1
fi

cd "$DIR"

for user in $(ls -d */)
 do
 for dirs in $(ls -d $user*)
  do
  echo $dirs
 done
done

IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

Run the above "test.sh" script like this:

```
bash test.sh /media/2C44138344134F48/RB1
```

or simply (if you are already in BASH and you have set the eXecutable flag)

```
./test.sh /media/2C44138344134F48/RB1
```

[Reference](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/handling-filenames-with-spaces-in-bash.html)

Comment: Strange. It works on my Ubuntu, using BASH shell. I missed the last line of the script a few minutes ago (the line that sets back the original IFS. Maybe you need to try in a new shell (just type 'bash')

Comment: I am also using ubuntu 11.10 and working on bash shell but I am still getting the error.

Comment: `ls` in backticks to drive a `for` loop is basically always wrong. http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#ls

Comment: With the wildcards fixed, I don't think you need to mess with `IFS` any longer.

Comment: Watch out for other characters in the above code though.  Things like files containing "../" type text will still throw it for a loop.

Comment: The last sentence of this answer is incorrect.  The 'for' does not look at IFS at all; IFS is used to split words after the expansion, so IFS only effects how '*' is expanded.  Also the default value of IFS is not a space character, but the 3 character string consisting of space, tab, newline.

Answer (score 2):

It would actually be easiest to use find:

```
find PATH -type d -name '* *'
```

Or if you need to do something with each result, consider piping it to xargs

```
find PATH -type d -name '* *' -print0 | xargs -0 run-some-command
```

Or if you just want all the directories safely escaped into arguments then:

```
find PATH -type d -print0 | xargs -0 run-some-command
```

Inside `run-some-command`, each argument to the script will be properly set to each directory name regardless of what characters it contains.

Comment: Agreed, maybe OP question is not in line with the post content. I think he wants to process all directories in a directory but his script fails because of the ones with space in the name.

Comment: Yes, I need to process al directories within it.

Answer (score 0):

The simple script below will do what you need.

```
#!/bin/bash

function usage() {
        echo "Usage: `basename $0` <dir-name>"
}


if [ "x$1" = "x" ]
then
        usage
        exit 0
fi

find "$1" -type 'd'
```